# Plot skeleton endpoints on the original image - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I skeletonize an image based on the code below. How can I plot the endpoints on the original image?

Code:

```
clc;
clear;
close all;
bw = imread('circles.png');
imshow(bw);
bw2 = bwmorph(bw,'remove');
figure
imshow(bw2)
bw3 = bwmorph(bw,'skel',Inf);
figure
imshow(bw3)

bw4 = bwmorph(bw3,'thin',Inf);
figure
imshow(bw4)

bw_endpoints = bwmorph(bw4, 'endpoints');
imshow(bw_endpoints)

[i_end,j_end] = find(bw_endpoints);
imshow(bw); hold on; 
plot(i_end,j_end,'o')
```

Comment: You should indicate what the issue is with your code. Are you seeing the points in the wrong locations? You probably want to switch the two arguments to `plot`.

Comment: just replace the order `plot(j_end,i_end,'r.')`